# Update table if other table update is successful

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I update table2 in the below code only if the updation in table1 is success?

```
$sql="update table1 set col1='abc' where col2='1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(that is success)
{
    $sql="update table2 set col1='cde' where col2='1'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`mysql_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function, which will return the number of rows just updated. Also, try to avoid using mysql_* functions in favor of mysqli_* or PDO, as they are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is highly recommended to **not** use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated as of [PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

You can check directly with the `$result` variable

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Update failed: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    $sql="update table2 set col1='cde' where col2='1'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the above query is succeeded so the `$result` variable will have the number 1 as $result else it will have another value so simply you can test it like this

```
if($result == 1)
 {
     //Your second update result
 }
```

Try this and tell me the result :)

Comment: @Jomin George : please When you ask a question update it by adding comments on answers if it was helpful and useful and also on answers that do not solve your problem so you can get the maximum help then if the problem is solved accept the most useful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) states that the return value of an update is true if the update worked and false otherwise so you can just go ahead and check the value of `$return` to see if the updated worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use only $result as it will always be true as long as the query didnt cause an error. If the Where clause has no hits, nothing is updated and no error is caused. So result would still be true.

Use mysql_affected_rows as Alex suggested to know how many record have been updated.

So do `if ($result && mysql_affected_rows() )` ...